# Spring Cloud Stream 3.0 StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am unable to configure custom handlers for my stream consumer using StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer.

```
@Bean
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer customizer() { 
        return fb -> {          
    fb.getStreamsConfiguration().put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomDeserializationHandler.class);
            fb.getStreamsConfiguration().put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_PRODUCTION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomEventErrorHandler.class);               
            fb.getStreamsConfiguration().forEach((k,v) -> System.err.println("Key , Value "+ k + " , " + v));
        };
    }
```

After setting the above in my spring boot @Configuration class and starting application, I still see defaults under SteamConfig. According to docs

> Blockquote

[customizer will be invoked by the binder right before the factory bean is started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_streamsbuilderfactorybean_customizer).

> Blockquote

But it seems like binder is not invoking StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer
**Is this a known issue ?**  I am using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams
with 2020.0.1 (spring-cloud.version) 2.4.2(spring boot)

```
021-03-11 11:52:04.386 [main] INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig - StreamsConfig values: 
    acceptable.recovery.lag = 10000
    application.id = service-stream
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    built.in.metrics.version = latest
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = 
    commit.interval.ms = 1000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
    default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
    default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
    default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
    default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde
    max.task.idle.ms = 0
    max.warmup.replicas = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two interfaces of the same name: One from [Spring Kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer.java) and another in [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer.java). The binder only takes into consideration the one from Spring Kafka. Please make sure that you are implementing that one. We have filed an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25608) in Boot to address this inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks @sobychacko that was indeed the case. Using the correct import statement causes the registration as expected.

Comment: Good to know. Feel free to accept the answer, just in case if anyone else having the same problem and come to this thread.

Comment: But the interface from spring-kafka is deprecated.

Comment: Spring Kafka deprecated `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` and provides a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer` instead to avoid the name clash with Spring Boot. See this issue for details: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1736

Answer (score 1):

This has been updated in spring cloud version 2020.0.3.
One can use `org.springframework.kafka.config.StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanConfigurer` instead.